# processamento de dados em python com pandas

Tags: python

presciso criar um codigo para responder a seguinte pergunta: 'Quantos filmes possuem avaliação >= 4.7, considerando apenas filmes avaliados na ultima data de avaliação do dataset?'

```
media= notas.groupby(by='Movie_Id', sort=False)['Rating'].mean().nlargest(5).round(1).reset_index()
data= notas['Date'].iloc[-1]
```

ele me retorna: 2004-06-02 que é a ultima data de avaliação da tabela.
agora eu presciso responder a pergunta acima baseada nessa data.

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi corretamente, você já tem o dataframe com a última data de avaliação, certo? Faltando apenas aplicar o filtro.

Caso seja isso, para aplicar o filtro basta fazer:

```
maiores_notas = notas.loc[notas.Rating >= 4.7]
```

Comment: ajudou sim. mais eu ainda to em duvida em relação a data